# How can I find the magnetic field of this system using the Biot-Savart law?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

I want to find out the [magnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field) at centre of this shape, whose radius increases from $0$ to $R$ by completing two loops. I have tried several approaches but I could not figure it out. I cannot find it anywhere on internet either, I have assumed current $I$ is flowing in this shape.

[image: refer to my question]

Comment: Are you assuming a 2d world?

Comment: No,  i see no reason to assume a 2d world

Comment: The issue is whether to interpret this spiral as the cross section of conducting sheets or really a curved wire. Furthermore, due to the abrupt termination, you'll have varying accumulation of charge at the extremities to satisfy conservation of charge, so magnetostatics does not apply.

Comment: It is a actual wire and you can think that end point are connected to a battery but wires used in those connections do not contribute to magnetic field

Comment: You can't exactly ignore the battery, you can only calculate the magnetic field of a conservative current distribution in magnetostatics. More prosaically, you have to always include the whole loop, so the details of the battery is relevant. Furthermore, finding an analytic solution is pretty hopeless in any case, but you can always simulate it numerically

Comment: Could you provide a mathematical expression for that spiral? If you do not have one yet, you should choose one.

Comment: based on the drawing, it's probably an Archimedes' spiral (for example in polar coordinates: $r=\frac{R\theta}{4\pi}$)

Answer (score 1):

Following  comments from others.

You have drawn a situation that magnetostatics simply cannot handle.

The divergence of this current distribution is non zero, meaning that the [Biot-Savart law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field) doesn't work.

I would also not advise using the full [Maxwell equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) to solve for the fields. Anyway,  since entering this distribution into the equations says that it follows this current  always. You will probably get infinite charge buildup over time, in reality this distribution evolves as the fields do, and so the current density is not fixed.

With that being said, if you still want to use Biot-Savart law for this, then you can still try. Although it isn't really valid as @Ipz has stated, This curve is $r=\frac{R\theta}{4\pi}$

This comes from:

$$r=\theta$$

Normalise it, so that when you go $1$ full turn [$2\pi$ radians] it is a radius of $1$

$$r = \frac{\theta}{2\pi}$$

Multiply by $R$ so that after 1 full turn it has a radius of $R$:

$$r = \frac{R\theta}{2\pi}$$

Change $\theta$ to $\frac{1}{2}\theta$

Such that $\theta$ now has to travel twice as far to get to the desired radius.

And thus:

$$r=\frac{R\theta}{4\pi}$$

However, to use this curve we want it in vector form:

$$\vec{r}(\theta)=\frac{R\theta}{4\pi}\hat r$$

$$dr = \frac{R}{4\pi} [\theta \frac{d\hat r}{d\theta} + \hat r] d\theta$$

Where:

$$\hat r = cos(\theta) \hat i + sin(\theta) \hat j$$